# Overlapping progress bars. How to clear past progress bar, when new one starts

Tags: javascript

I have the following function which starts a 10 second progress bar when it's called.

```
function timer() {
  var timeleft = 10;
  var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
   if(timeleft <= 0){
     clearInterval(downloadTimer);
   }
   document.getElementById("timer-bar").value = 10 - timeleft;
   timeleft -= 1;
  }, 1000);
};
```

It's used as a sort of visual countdown. Sometimes the function is called a 2nd or 3rd time, before the progress bar has completed.  This causes overlapping progress bars in the same "timer-bar" element.  Is there a way to clear the prior progress bar before starting a new one?  Thank you very much, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to declare `downloadTimer` and `timeleft` outside your function, as global variables:

```js
var downloadTimer;
var timeleft;

function timer() {
  timeleft = 10;
  clearInterval(downloadTimer);
  downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
    if(timeleft <= 0){
      clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    }
    document.getElementById("timer-bar").value = 10 - timeleft;
    timeleft -= 1;
  }, 1000);
};
```

```html
<span id="timer">
  <progress value="0" max="10" id="timer-bar"></progress>
</span>

<input type="button" onclick="timer();" value="restart">
```

This way calling `timer()` would create a new timer by overwriting the unfinished timer.

Comment: It overwrites the old one, thank you.  However every time it's overwritten, while the progress bar starts from the beginning, it progresses erratically and not consistently each time.

Comment: This is the html code i am using too, thank you for any feedback you can provide: <span id="timer"><progress value="0" max="10" id="timer-bar"></progress></span>

Comment: Ok I edited, it seems like you need to use the clearInterval() method right before you create the new timer, because even if we redefine the downloadTimer var, the old setinterval was still active...